# Unable to open saved dxp file. Tibco spotfire

Tags: c#, tibco, spotfire

I am developing custom data source in tibco spotfire. I open a datasorce using professional player. Then I want to save this opened chart and after the chart is saved I am trying to open it using spotfire web player. But have no luck.

When I open this chart using spotfire prof it works. Also I have checked logs and found the following:

There were no matching columns.
 Missing columns: nameColumsHere, nameColumsHere, nameColumsHere
There are some inconsistencies and some data might not be shown accurately.

Comment: Are you using the same user credentials in the web player and the client? Sounds like a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a client with the same issue and it indeed was a permissions issue.

Make sure your datasource has the appropriate permissions on it to allow access from the web and/or your user has the appropriate permissions to access it when using the web client.